# Visual studio 2015 Android NDK application development Build failure visual c++

Tags: android, c++, android-ndk, visual-studio-2015

I installed Visual Studio 2015 and try to develop an Android application using cross platform C++. I just created the project and I am trying to build it but face this error:

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line
Error   MSB3073 The command ""C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Apps\apache-ant-1.9.3\\bin\ant.bat" debug -Dout.final.file="c:\Users\salman\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\Android1\ARM\Debug\Android1.apk"" exited with code 1.   Android1    C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\MDD\Android\V140\Android.Common.targets    293
```

However, I have checked the directory and the `android1.apk` does not exist. And it is not created when I build the project (which sometimes succeeds sometimes fails resulting in this error).

Here are the system environment variables I have:

```
ADT_HOME: C:\Users\salman\AppData\Local\Android\sdk

ANT_HOME: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Apps\apache-ant-1.9.3\

JAVA_HOME: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_05

PATH: %JAVA_HOME%\bin;%ADT_HOME%\tools;%ADT_HOME%\platform-tools;%ANT_HOME%\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\iCLS Client\;C:\Program Files\Intel\iCLS Client\;%SystemRoot%\system32;%SystemRoot%;%SystemRoot%\System32\Wbem;%SYSTEMROOT%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Skype\Phone\;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\120\DTS\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\Client SDK\ODBC\110\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\120\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\120\Tools\Binn\ManagementStudio\;%USERPROFILE%\.dnx\bin;C:\Program Files\Microsoft DNX\Dnvm\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Windows Performance Toolkit\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\120\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Emulator Manager\1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs\;
```

I made some changes to the variables after looking at some forums but that didn't work. I am hoping for some guidance here.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem, solved by opening the "SDK Manager" and installing a bunch of older SDK Platforms ... API 19, 20, 22. I can build and debug apps from Visual Studio 2015 on my Nexus 7 now and in the Visual Studio Android Emulator.

The "SDK Manager" is in "C:\Users\\AppData\Local\Android\sdk" if you've also installed (like I did) Android Studio.